# coc.nvim Add icons in suggestions menu

Tags: autocomplete, neovim, coc.nvim, tsserver

[Screen Shot from Termux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HleD.png)

I want to add Icons (like VSCode) in suggestion on the k(keyword), v(variable).

I tried searching with suggest keyword on **coc-settings.json** as well on **duckduckgo.com**. But nothing found to change the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can custom the kind label with `suggest.completionItemKindLabels`.

Check `:h coc-config-suggest-completionItemKindLabels`.